# Facebook app redirecting to wrong application

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I have two applications current on Apple Store, both share part of code, but are correctly configure to work as two different applications.

Facebook login was working correctly on version `FBSDKCoreKit (4.39.1)` and `FBSDKLoginKit (4.39.1)`, but when I runned `pod update` and these pods where updated to version `5.0.0` login with facebook stops working correctly, even after I make the necessary changes on my login flow.

The problem is that if I hit button `Login with Facebook` of the first app, if I choose to use Facebook App it redirects to my second App, not the first one. But, if I login on web modal, it works fine.

I have a different Facebook App Id for both apps, and both implement `Login with Facebook`.

My `AppDelegate.swift` is configured like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}


func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let handle = FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

    return handle
}
```

(Both apps share same `AppDelegate.swift`)

And my `LoginViewController` is configured:

```
@IBAction func loginWithFacebookClicked() {
    let fbLoginManager: LoginManager = LoginManager()

    if AccessToken.current != nil {
        fbLoginManager.logOut()
    }

    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .browser

    fbLoginManager.logIn(permissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil && !result!.isCancelled) {
            if let token = AccessToken.current?.tokenString {
                self.facebookLogin(token)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apps has different `LoginViewController`, but code is the same.

I do not got any error, and both logins are working, just the callback to app that is not. Please, if anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: have you set callback url to your project?

Comment: i don't know how to do this, could you help me? The strange thing is that it was working before :/

Comment: have you add `fb12**your fb ID**432` in `Target>Info` under `URL Types` ??

Comment: @PratikPrajapati yes, it was working fine before.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?